# Many components communicating simultaneously in Angular 2 app - should I use Redux or ngrx

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am building a reactive Angular 2 application. It's a content analytics app with interactive charts. Every time user interacts with one of them, different data is displayed and other charts that were interacted with default to their original state.

So far I've been successfully using RxJS for inter-component communication but as I add more charts and components, the number of interactions multiplies exponentially. The number of messages I have to keep sending between components is getting out of hand.

Inspired by Redux I use Angular service as an app state store for more important data but it's not good enough anymore. It looks to me that I need to take a leap towards one of these:

- Redux,
- @ngrx
- other solution I don't see

I have a general idea about Redux and to lesser extent about ngrx, but would like to know which one will be better in my scenario. Is there a better solution than these two?

Comment: `@ngrx` is an implementation of the Redux *pattern* for Angular. Your question makes it sound like they're two different things. I tend to see them as two *different implementations* of the *same concept* (I know I'm simplifying). If you want to use the Redux pattern, you're better off using `@ngrx` than the "raw" Redux.js library. Unless... you need to use redux middleware (which will only be compatible with Redux itself).

Comment: Yeah, after going through a lot of resources I found this discussion to be the most explanatory as what are the benefits of using ngrx over Redux or even RxJS (after all I could make my appState a Subject and subscribe to it in all components).

Comment: I forgot to put the link to the discussion https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/16

Comment: ngrx is seriously awesome ! Thinking of your store as a stream is something I really like. Easy to subscribe, combine other streams, etc. @AngularFrance when you say "Unless... you need to use redux middleware (which will only be compatible with Redux itself)" ? It's not totally true as many of them are already available for ngrx. Ex @ngrx/store-devtools, ngrx-store-freeze ... I'm also using redux-batched-actions and it's not an ngrx version.

Comment: @Maxime. Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. :)